# Moment.js Date not working on tablet

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am working with my script of just displaying the date and I'm using duda platform for it
however the tablet version is not working while the desktop and the mobile is just fine. My script is pasted in the end of body and I'm using moment.js

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
//for desktop mobile display date today
window.onload = function(){
    var a = moment().format('LL');
    document.getElementById("dateToday").innerHTML = a;

//for tablet
    var b = moment().format('LL');
    document.getElementById("dateTodayTab").innerHTML = b;
}


</script>
```

The console says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null.
Here is my html code for desktop and tablet. I inspected the tablet element and the height was 0px while the desktop version was not. Care to point what's my mistake here?

```
<h4> The date today is :<span id="dateToday"></span></h4>
<h4> The date today is :<span id="dateTodayTab"></span></h4>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that it is specifically Moment.js that causes this problem? Does it work if you just have `var a = "foo";` and `var b = "bar";`? It sounds very unlikely based on the information given.

Comment: Consider your errors more carefully - the one you are getting tells you exactly what is wrong. "Cannot set property 'innerHtml' of null means that the element that you are trying to set the date on is not found in the dom, either because it is not there or your DOM is malformed. This has nothing to with moment, but is most likely due to your missing close tag on the span.

Comment: Oh sorry and thanks for pointing that out moment.js is working on desktop and mobile versions but only the tablet.My element exist you can see it here or preview it, it was a separate element for desk and tab:
http://thecameldevelopers.editor.multiscreensite.com/preview/8367b6dd

Comment: Well of course it doesn't work if  the `dateToday` element doesn't exist at all in the tablet version. The code that tries to access it throws an error and the script execution halts, it never gets to the part that tries to put the date to the `dateTodayTab` element. You'll have to check if the element exists first (`if(document.getElementById("dateToday") !== null)`) before trying to manipulate it.

Comment: @JJJ oh! wow thanks for the idea! It's now working!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fixed! Thanks to @JJJ the problem is that my element in tablet was hidden so it can't be found that's why my script stops and spits out the error of Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null because it doesn't exist in the tablet mode. I made a two function on my script that will execute if the user is viewing at desktop and tablet only :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
//for desktop mobile display date today
window.onload = function(){

    var dateverify = document.getElementById("dateToday");
    var desktopDate = function(){
        //for desktop
        var a = moment().format('LL');
        document.getElementById("dateToday").innerHTML = a;
    }
    var tabletDate = function(){
        //for tablet
        var b = moment().format('LL');
        document.getElementById("datedate").innerHTML = b;
    }
    if(dateverify !== null){
        desktopDate();
    }
    else{
        tabletDate();
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML example the span is not closed

```
<h4> The date today is :<span id="dateToday"></span</h4>
<h4> The date today is :<span id="dateTodayTab"></span</h4>
```

It should be like this:

```
<h4> The date today is :<span id="dateToday"></span></h4>
<h4> The date today is :<span id="dateTodayTab"></span></h4>
```

(Not positive that is the solution but you might start there)

Comment: yea thanks for pointing out. You can preview it here if you want for clearer:
http://thecameldevelopers.editor.multiscreensite.com/preview/8367b6dd
it was a seperate element for desktop and tablet.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function(){
  var a = moment().format('LL');
  document.getElementById("dateToday").innerHTML = a;
  //for tablet
  var b = moment().format('LL');
  document.getElementById("dateTodayTab").innerHTML = b;
}
</script>
<h4>The date today is :<span id="dateToday"></span></h4>
<h4>The date today is :<span id="dateTodayTab"></span></h4>
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/Socramg/vL92buto/1/)

Comment: Hi thanks for the demo I already tried that in my codepen it works, but when I transfer it to the tab version its not working you can take a preview here:
http://thecameldevelopers.editor.multiscreensite.com/preview/8367b6dd/

Comment: Hi, that is wierd because I do see it. Here a ss: https://postimg.org/image/ykdhqbzlt/

Answer (score -1):

I think that window.onload event is fired too early, and script can't get element since it is not rendered yet. Try using

```
window.document.body.onload
```

instead.